# Material UI Grid item or TextField padding / margin

Tags: material-ui, textfield, padding, react-hook-form

I made a component to standarize my text imputs (for forms using Material UI and React-Hook-Forms).

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const inputSm = {xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 6, lg: 6, xl: 4};
const inputLg = {xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 12, lg: 6, xl: 6};

function setSize(size){
    if (size === "s") return inputSm;
    if (size === "m") return inputLg;
    return inputLg;
}

export function StdTextInput({label, name, register, helperText = " ", errors, errorText = " ", 
                              size = "m", fullWidth = true, autoComplete = "on", variant = "standard", 
                              inputProps = {}, validationRules = {}})
{
    let inputSize = setSize(size);
    const isError = !!errors[name];  //!! para forzar a booleano
    return(
        <Grid item {...inputSize}>
            <TextField
                label={label}
                {...register(name, validationRules)}
                helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message || errorText : helperText}
                fullWidth={fullWidth}
                size="small" 
                autoComplete={autoComplete}
                variant={variant}   
                InputProps={{
                    ...inputProps,
                    style: {
                      paddingLeft: '8px', 
                      paddingRight: '8px'
                    },
                  }}
                error={isError}
                >
            </TextField>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

I use this components in this way:

```
<Box>
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    <StdTextInput label="Email" name="email" register={register} helperText="Ingresar un mail con una @ y al menos 1 punto"
                                  errors={errors} errorText="Este campo es requerido" size="l" 
                                  validationRules={{required: true, 
                                                    pattern: {value: /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w+$/, 
                                                              message: "La dirección de correo electrónico no es válida"}
                                                    }}/>

                    <StdTextInput label="Teléfono" name="telefono" register={register} errors={errors} size="s" validationRules={{validate: {validaTelefono}}}/>

                    <StdTextInput label="Nombre" name="nombre" register={register} errors={errors} validationRules={{required: "El campo Nombre es requerido"}}/>

                    <StdTextInput label="Apellido" name="apellido" register={register} errors={errors}/>
    
                </Grid>
            </Box>
```

I have a problem with the margins or paddings of each field, the fields are glued to the edges of the form and I would like them to leave a small padding.

I've tried with InputProps={{
...inputProps,
style: {
paddingLeft: '8px',
paddingRight: '8px'
},
}}
but the fields didnt move. I have tried adding margin to the style of the Grid item and it seems to work but in the example above Apellido falls to another line (the margin plus de fullWidth of the textField is too much.

Ive tried with padding and margin in Grid item, with padding and marging in the TextField without the desired result...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem adding a paddingX to the Box that wrap the imput.